# Optional parameters in routing ending with paging parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, global-asax

I've been creating a blog, which contains of 3 diffrent views. 
- Overview
- Post Detail
- Filtered overview

The filtered overview is based on blogposts which contain a certain tag, to make the url pretty I would love to get it like to be able to add optional parameters like the following:

```
mydomain.com/blog/<tagname>/<page>
mydomain.com/blog/<tagname1>/<tagname2>/<page>
mydomain.com/blog/<tagname1>/<tagname2>/<tagname3>/<page>
```

The pageing parameter is semi-optional, if not there it should be 1. But in most cases it will be there. 
Are there ways to solve this issue in a nice way? 
The only way I could think of was creating a lot of lines in my global asax which makes it kind of messy in my opinion.

Thanks in advance, DerDee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom route:

```
public class BlogRoute : Route
{
    public BlogRoute()
        : base(
            "blog/{*info}", 
            new RouteValueDictionary(new 
            { 
                controller = "blog", 
                action = "index" 
            }),
            new MvcRouteHandler()
        )
    { 
    }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var rd = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
        if (rd == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var info = rd.Values["info"] as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(info))
        {
            return rd;
        }

        var parts = info.Split('/');
        if (parts.Length < 1)
        {
            return rd;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == parts.Length - 1)
            {
                int page;
                if (int.TryParse(parts[i], out page))
                {
                    rd.Values["page"] = page;
                }
            }

            if (!rd.Values.ContainsKey("page"))
            {
                rd.Values[string.Format("tags[{0}]", i)] = parts[i];
            }
        }

        return rd;
    }
}
```

which will be registered in `Global.asax`:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.Add("BlogRoute", new BlogRoute());

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

and then you could have a BlogController:

```
public class BlogController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string[] tags, int? page)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I was looking for, at the moment I'm busy Implementing something different but as soon as I have time for Ill try to implement this method. Thanks a lot for you help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have optional parameters come before required parameters in MVC. One solution would be to put the paging parameter before the tags parameter:

```
mydomain.com/blog/<page>/<tagname>
mydomain.com/blog/<page>/<tagname1>/<tagname2>
mydomain.com/blog/<page>/<tagname1>/<tagname2>/<tagname3>
```

You can then give a default value to the page parameter in your route:

```
MapRoute(null, "blog/{page}/{*tagNames}", 
    new { controller = "Blogs", action = "ByPageAndTags", page = 1 });
```

Comment: This is a solution, but not fully what I want, since the paging parameter is always at the end I would like to keep it consistent in the URL. Right now i'm working on another issue but try to implement Darin's sollution asap, if this wont work I guess i have no other option as to move it. Thanks for your help